# Use different models to read data from different databases in django

Tags: python, django

I need a way of reading data in django from different DBs using different models, because models and fields in the db have changed between the projects.

What I try to do is this:

```
from sbo.core import models as sbo_core_models
from sbo_cloud.core import models as cloud_core_models

company_details = sbo_core_models.CompanyDetails.objects.using('sbo').filter(company=sbo_company).order_by("id")[0]
new_company_details = cloud_core_models.CompanyDetails.objects.get(id=int(reply['id']))
```

the model that actually gets used for the new_company_details is actually sbo_core_models.CompanyDetails and not cloud_core_models.CompanyDetails because it is missing properties that would appear in the second one.

any ideea why this might happen and what I am doing wrong, from what i've seen it uses the models that I import first, no matter what model I tell it to use.

I am using python2.7 and django 1.3.3

Answer (score 0):

All you need it's on the Django documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/multi-db/

I think that the best solution for your case is a database router.

Comment: DB routing only helps me to assure the DB the model reads from is ok, but I do not have a problem with the DB but with the model, It's not using the specified model but the first imported one.